# How to get a TreeListView in Avalonia

Tags: treeview, avalonia

I have a TreeView with a similar code in it's xaml file which displays multiple values for each row.

```
<TreeView Items="{Binding Items}">
        <TreeView.DataTemplates>
        <TreeDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding SubItems}">
          <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}" Grid.Column="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </TreeDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.DataTemplates>
</TreeView>
```

[Current TreeView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G61RR.png)

However I want the view to be like this [Expected View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph9lx.png) where the values in column 2 and beyond shouldn't shift as the level increases. Is there a way to adjust the spacing between the columns such that they fall under the same heading?
Also I want to have a consistent view across different platforms.

Comment: You mean that you want to display the sub items in the same level as the root items without a margin, right ?